# Identify ipv6 address in linux

Tags: linux, ipv6

I can see three ipv6 address in my linux box. I am not able to figure out how "inet6 fd01:0:102:b:250:56ff:feb2:a0de/64 scope global dynamic " is being configured in my box. Rest 2 i understand and know abt them.

New to ipv6 please help to know abt this address.

2: eth0:  mtu 1500 qlen 1000

```
inet6 fd01:0:102:b:250:56ff:feb2:a0de/64 scope global dynamic 
   valid_lft 2591771sec preferred_lft 604571sec
inet6 fc00:10:166:1::13/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::250:56ff:feb2:a0de/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

- Sachin

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: How " inet6 fd01:0:102:b:250:56ff:feb2:a0de/64 scope global dynamic" is configured?                                                                                               After reading i am guessing this is may be configured by IPv6 SLAAC auto configurations. Disabling ipv6 autoconf may help. Currently this is enabled " net.ipv6.conf.eth0.autoconf = 1"

Answer (score 0):

According to [RFC 4193](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4193#page-3), `fd01:0:102:b:250:56ff:feb2:a0de` is a valid *Unique Local IPv6 Unicast Address*, which is not routed on the public internet but can be used for local networks in company intranets or home networks. The IPv4-equivalent would addresses from blocks like `192.68.0.0/16` or `10.0.0.0/8`.

The second address looks weird though: `fc00:10:166:1::13/64` is of the reserved `fc00::/7` space but it's use is not defined yet, see also the  [Unique Local Address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_local_address#Definition) Wikipedia article.